# Symfony2. I can't set Content-Length header

Tags: symfony, header, content-length

i am new on Simfony and I am trying to set a Content-Length header in my response.

This is my controller action:

```
public function homepageAction() {

   $content= $this>renderView('AcmeBlogBundle:Pages/homepage:homepage_content.html.twig');

   $response= new Response();

   $response->setContent($content);

   $response->headers->set('Content-Length: 1736233495'); // value added manually

   return $response;

} // homepage
```

i obtain an error 500 internal server error.

Comment: What does the error log of your webserver say? E.g. /var/log/apache2/error.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to  `$response->headers->set('Content-Length', 1736233495);` ?

EDIT : [Documentation](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ResponseHeaderBag.html#method_set)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the "-" missing in the "$this>renderView" part ?